# g2p-seq2seq train command running indefinitely

Tags: cmusphinx

I searched everywhere for adding a capping for training an acoustic model using g2p-seq2seq command but it is running indefinitely using below command. If anyone knows how to restrict g2p-seq2seq to stop in case loss is not decreasing then please let me know.

```
g2p-seq2seq --train train_dictionary.dic --model_dir model_path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of epochs to run with `--max_epochs`, for example 10 epochs.